# Injecting new section into PE file. Having trouble

Tags: c++, code-injection, portable-executable

So I've been spending the last 2 days trying to inject a new section into a PE file, but unfortunuately, without much luck. I am able to dis-assemble, and then re-assemble the whole PE, but when I try to inject a new section, the file becomes corrupt. As soon as I try to launch the file, I get the useless error message "This program cannot be run.". I wanted to try and fix it myself, but I'm completely stuck. Here is my code, there are a couple of temporary hacks in there for debugging purposes, which I will get rid of later.

My code: http://pastebin.com/ZfZqUWUG

Sorry for the rather large file, but the problem is that I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appriciated.

UPDATE

My goal is to write a packer which would allow me to secure exe files. I'd have a builder, which encrypts all the existing sections, adds a new executable section, and change the entry point to that section. The code in the new section would decrypt the other sections, and jump to the original entry point.

I can see the new .inj section with PE explorer, and it also displays the data "Test".

Comment: Either you're doing something wrong in the copying, or you're building the headers wrong. Try opening the exe in something like OllyDbg, it *might* give you more of an idea of what's wrong. You could also try some PE validator, for example http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/PE_Validator_Script. I can't see you updating the checksum, for example.

Comment: There's actually so many things you might be doing wrong that it's pretty much impossible to answer your question. You have to get to the bottom of the problem, or you'll have to provide some test data as well (input exe, input inj, output exe). What is it you're actually trying to do? If you're eg. trying to build a self-extracting archive, there's easier ways. If you're trying to add resources or something like that, there's tools to do that correctly.

Comment: Updated the OP with some more information. Thank you for that script, it has helped me fix the SizeOfImage, but it seems to give 2 false positives, it does that for every program I open with it

Comment: Hi, sorry for commenting on an old question. Did you ever get this to work? Any literature/resources you know of that can help with this? :)

Comment: @Tobias it's been quite a long time since I did anything PE related. I don't think I ever got it to work because I moved on to other things unfortunately. Maybe I can still help you though, what are you stuck on? Icezillon's tutorials helped me out a lot with the PE structure.

Comment: @user2073973 I'm writing a packer for application distribution purposes. :) Right now I'm getting the hang of it, especially the PE structure, and how Windows handles it. The thing that might become tricky is the code injection part, but I'm slowly getting there. :)